# why bits/libc-header-start.h folder is included in stdio.h header

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc

I am unable to compile to c program for 32bit machine from 64bit linux machine using command `gcc -m32 -Werror a.c -o a`
It shows me the error

```
In file included from a.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I check the stdio.h in `/usr/include/stdio.h`
here in my machine`Linux kali 4.19.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.28-2kali1 (2019-03-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux` the line  `#include <bits/libc-header-start.h>` is included while in other ubuntu 64 bit this line is not included

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int functionFunction(char *param)
{
    char *localString = "Conjunction Function";
    int localInt = 0xdeadbeef;
    char localString2[10];
    strcpy(localString2,param);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *localString = "Main Function";
    int localInt = 0x11223344;
    functionFunction(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The header files in the `bits` directory are internal to the library, and may be included as needed. If you're missing such a header you could possibly not have installed all the required development packages.

Comment: Can the source be compiled for 64bit?

Comment: OT: regarding: `functionFunction(argv[1]);`  it is never a good idea to access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure to user has actually entered the expected command line parameter

Answer (score 8):

#### Try with installing gcc-multilib

`sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`

if that doesn't work,
`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` (you could also try to reinstall the headers, and then reboot)

Comment: I love you :) Worked for me

Comment: @nmu Why thank you! Happy I could help ^_^ Wishes from Sweden!